# saving data to interal memory with async task (newboston tutorials sample) error it has progress bar

Tags: android, android-asynctask, save, progress-bar, fileinputstream

this is my first post here

i'm new, so be good with me!

i'm following travis's tutorials and it goes to saving data and using async task

i really focused but i can't find out whats wrong with my code, so i posted here! :
I added the logcat!
it worked without async and progress bar (both save and load)

latest changes!:
i fixed the progress bar but loadwithasync class is not working, i mean this line:
I think this must return the Srting ld and set that in text view res. but it is not looking this way! why travis from mybringback! didn't wrote the line like Strig s = new loadWith..... ? can u tell me where is the problem! i'm confused and i don't know how to debug properly!! 
new loadWithAsyncTask().execute(FILENAME);

```
 public class SaveAndLoadInternal extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText file, data;
TextView res;
FileInputStream fis;
FileOutputStream fos;
String FILE_NAME;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.save_load_internal);
    Button load, save;
    file = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSLIfile);
    data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSLIdata);
    res = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSLIres);
    load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSLIload);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSLIsave);

    // set file and close it!

    load.setOnClickListener(this);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    FILE_NAME = file.getText().toString();
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bSLIload:
        //Commented just for doing some tweaks! run 
        //loading process in another thread to give UI thread rest :D for          avoid hanging!
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        String ld = "LOADING FAILED!";

  /*            try {
            fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
            byte[] b = new byte[fis.available()];
            while (fis.read(b) != -1) {
                ld = new String(b);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        res.setText(ld);
 */
        new loadWithAsyncTask ().execute(FILE_NAME);
        // execute will run doInBackground method!

        break;
    case R.id.bSLIsave:
        String sd = data.getText().toString();
/*
        // one way to save in file is below! must work but it isn't!
        File f = new File(FILE_NAME);
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME); 
            fos.write(sd.getBytes());
            fos.close();
            res.setText("SAVING DONE!");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 */
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(sd.getBytes());
            fos.close();
            res.setText("SAVING DONE!");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
 // /*
// first param: what is being passed in (FILE_NAME) 
// second param for progress bar (we use integer here)
// third one is what we will return! (the saved text! String ld)
public class loadWithAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    ProgressDialog pd;
    String Ld = "LOADING FAILED!";
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    // this gonna called first
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        // example: setting up variables or something else!
        pd = new ProgressDialog(SaveAndLoadInternal.this);
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pd.setMax(100);
        pd.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) { 

        //for progress dialog
        for(int i =0 ; i< 20 ; i++){
            publishProgress(5);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(88);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        pd.dismiss();

        try {
            fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
            byte[] b = new byte[fis.available()];
            res.setText(String.valueOf(fis.available()));
            while (fis.read(b) != -1) {
                Ld = new String(b);
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fis.close();
                //return the string!
                return Ld;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    // progress of loading in example!
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress){

        pd.incrementProgressBy(progress[0]);
    }

}// */
    }
```

Comment: What is the error? Could you post your LogCat? Also, post the content of your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The main focus of this site is to help answer specific programming questions. Unfortunately, you forgot to ask yours.

Comment: I added the logcat!
it worked without async

Comment: i didn't post the manifest becuase as id said it worked without async task. the manifest must be ok if i don't need to add permission or ...!

and i don't know how to add manifest here, :D

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the error, you'll see that `onProgressUpdate()` throws a NPE. Looking at the code, there are two possibilities: 1. `pd` is null or 2. `progress` is null. Add a breakpoint or some logging there to see what exactly is going on.

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress){
    pd.incrementProgressBy(progress[0]);
}
```

Comment: i made some changes pd is working. i got an output from progress it's working, now my problem is why ld doesn't fill with data?
the content of this string is'nt changing
and i edited the code above to my current code!

Comment: something else! the code must work without this function? right?
it just give the user a visual iterface of updating the bar. am i right?